# Unable to install Java on Windows 10 (1603 Error)

Tags: java, installation, windows-8.1, windows-10

I tried to download Java on my laptop (which has windows 10) but i keep getting a 1603 error. My computer used to have windows 8.1 and it did not work back then either

I appreciate any advice to solve or work around this problem

Answer (score 1):

I have had this problem. I was able to fix it thanks to a co-worker. The problem started happening after I installed HP Unified Functional Testing (UFT, aka QTP). Installing this product changes the Windows environment variables used by Java. He told me the following:  "So change the names of JAVA_OPTIONS, IBM_JAVA_OPTIONS, JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS to something else (both in system and user variables) and delete any Java folder(in Program Files (x86) or Program Files) which gets installed despite the error. Restart the system and then try installing Java."

Actually, all I did was rename the environment variables and run the installer. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not related to win 10, but might help someone who is having similar problem in windows 7 machine and not able to install jre 32 bit version. 
the work around to this is once you downloaded the jre, copy the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\javaw.exe" and paste it under java runtime environment settings which is found -Java Control panel>java>view

Answer (score 0):

I think you downloaded the wrong version. If your laptop support x64 bit software you should download Java 1.8 x64 version.

Here is the link. 
https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Answer (score 0):

First you should close the browser because if any webpage will use Java, it will cause conflict. Then do **custom installation**, i.e. install in some other folder other than default folder and point environment variable to newly installed Java location. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem for a month now. I tried everything on my windows 8, but I couldn't get the latest java on it. When I tried to install java on an empty computer, the 64 bit version did not go through (error 1603) and I realized the problem didn't come from an old java install and I install 32 bit. it worked on the new computer with windows 7 and on my computer running 8.1.

note: I had deleted all the java versions before going through with it.

Answer (score 0):

To fix java 1603 error you have to follow few simple steps.

1. First of all remove all old java version.
2. Then remove some windows update file which might be reason of this
   error.  Like KB2918614 update.
3. After that download and Install latest version of java and activate
   java in browser. Now everything will be fine you can test the java
   version on java website...

For explained and easy solution to java 1603 error follow this link: http://protechguides.com/java-error-code-1603-solved/

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error on Windows 8.1 and when I checked with Oracle web site, they said that is is not yet resolved, and under investigation. They also showed a link for off-line installation as an alternative arrangement. However, upon investigation of my system, i found out that the available space in C drive was only about 20 MB or so. I cleared my system and provided enough space. When I tried with the extra space, I didn't encounter any error. May be, you could try with a better free space...